# How to deconvolute a 2D data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe

I created a data frame in which columns A and B contain subcolumns. Here is an example:

```
colnames(df) 
#[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"

colnames(df$A)
#[1] "X1" "X2" "X3" "X4"

colnames(df$B)
#[1] "X1" "X2"
```

My question is how to deconvolute this structure into:

```
colnames(df)
#[1] "A.X1" "A.X2" "A.X3" "A.X4" "B.X1" "B.X2"
```

example:

```
structure(list(Name = 1:5, A = structure(list(X1 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("1", "5"), class = "factor"), X2 = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("2", "4"), class = "factor"), X3 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("3", "4"), class = "factor"), X4 = structure(c(2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", "5"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X1", 
"X2", "X3", "X4"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame"), 
    B = structure(list(X1 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
    "5"), class = "factor"), X2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L), .Label = c("2", "4"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("X1", 
    "X2"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")), .Names = c("Name", 
"A", "B"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: use `dput` to make a reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `unnest()` function from the `tidyr` package.

First let's create some sample data. Let me know if this isn't how your data look.

```
library(tidyverse) # Loads tidyr, tibble, and other useful packages

df <- tibble(A = list(tibble(X1 = rnorm(327), X2 = rnorm(327),
             X3 = rnorm(327), X4 = rnorm(327))),
             B = list(tibble(X1 = rnorm(327), X2 = rnorm(327))))
```

Now `unnest` and you're almost done.

```
df <- unnest(df)
```

All that's left is renaming the columns, since `unnest` comes up with its own names automatically.

```
colnames(df) <- c("A.X1", "A.X2", "A.X3", "A.X4", "B.X1", "B.X2")
```

Comment: got error when trying to unnest:
Error: data_frames can only contain 1d atomic vectors and lists

Comment: please see the structure of my data frame in the update post above

Comment: Yes, but cannot get them as "1D" data frame